# server throws error with Prosys and Matrikon clients on events

Tags: node-opcua

I have been working through the examples in the node-opcua book which has been very helpful (and will be awesome when it is done!!!!). However, I have run into a problem when using the Prosys and Matrikon clients when the server is posting events. Specifically, the server crashes:

```
Users/brbl/Projects/GitHub/opcua-tutorial/node_modules/node-opcua-address-space/src/alarms_and_conditions/check_where_clause.ts:120
    }
     ^
Error: Only OfType operator are allowed in checkWhereClause
    at Object.checkWhereClause (/Users/brbl/Projects/GitHub/opcua-tutorial/node_modules/node-opcua-address-space/src/alarms_and_conditions/check_where_clause.ts:120:6)
    at MonitoredItem._on_opcua_event (/Users/brbl/Projects/GitHub/opcua-tutorial/node_modules/node-opcua-server/source/monitored_item.ts:833:10)
    at UAObject.emit (events.js:214:15)
    at UAObject.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at UAObject._bubble_up_event (/Users/brbl/Projects/GitHub/opcua-tutorial/node_modules/node-opcua-address-space/src/ua_object.ts:161:20)
    at UAObject.raiseEvent (/Users/brbl/Projects/GitHub/opcua-tutorial/node_modules/node-opcua-address-space/src/ua_object.ts:144:14)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/brbl/Projects/GitHub/opcua-tutorial/my_event_server.ts:95:11)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
```

Any guidance on how to fix the problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please update node-ocpua to the latest version ( currently 2.6.4)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am on 2.6.4. The problem can be easily replicated by using the demo_server_with_alarm. Once Prosys connects choose "event view", and you will see the problem. Thanks for doing node-opcua, and for writing the book!

Comment: OK, thank you , I can reproduce, it is better to track this issue inside node-opcua github. let's create an issue.

Comment: (see https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/issues/810)

Comment: node-opcua@2.7 onward now supports WhereClauses generated by Prosys and Matrikon;